# Reuse multiple shapes in single append

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

If I have a bunch of flowchart nodes:

```
var nodes = [
  {NodeType: "prep", x:50, y:50,  height:40, width: 160},
  {NodeType: "io",   x:50, y:125, height:40, width: 160}, 
  {NodeType: "io",   x:50, y:200, height:40, width: 160}
]
```

And I want to represent them all as rectangles, it's quite easy to do this in a single append:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

But what if I want them to be different shapes based on their type (IO and Preparation in my example above)?

I hacked up a way to do it with a dictionary of path functions instead of rectangles (full code at http://bl.ocks.org/4659227). Each path function accepts height and width.

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(nodes).enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return flow_shapes[d.NodeType](d.height, d.width);})
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
  });
```

But it seems like there must be a better standard way to do this. Any ideas?

I'm also concerned about the performance of the above code on a large node list, though I haven't done any stress testing of it yet.

Comment: Probably 50-75, but I also hope to do some drag & drop and editing, so there will be some re-rendering involved.

Comment: I don't think there will be any big performance issues less than 100 shapes. Drag & drop and re-rendering is easy when you using D3's event and selector expression.