# How to create more than one d3 polygon

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have edited this question a little bit from when I posted it. Here is the new code:
Here is my code:

```
        var elementTags = ["Google", 4, "Wikipedia", "Yahoo!", "Cindy"];
        var _s32 = (Math.sqrt(3)/2);
        var A = 75;
        var _counter = 0;
        var xDiff;
        var yDiff;
        var pointData = [[A+xDiff, 0+yDiff], [A/2+xDiff, (A*_s32)+yDiff], [-A/2+xDiff, (A*_s32)+yDiff], [-A+xDiff, 0+yDiff],
        [-A/2+xDiff, -(A*_s32)+yDiff], [A/2+xDiff, -(A*_s32)+yDiff], [A+xDiff, 0+yDiff]];
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body") //create container
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1000)
                .attr("height", 1000);

        var enterElements = svgContainer.selectAll("path.area") //draw elements
                .data([pointData]).enter().append("path")
                .style("fill", "#ff0000")
                .attr("d", d3.svg.area());
```

What I want to do is create a new hexagon for each `elementTags` value. Each new hexagon should have a randomized xDiff and yDiff, and each time the value of `_counter` should go up by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation, described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571826/reuse-multiple-shapes-in-single-append). I put together a code example which you can find here:
http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/4659227

The key idea is that the path-generating function can be called during the append of each data point:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(nodes).enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return flow_shapes[d.NodeType](d.height, d.width);})
```

It's hard to tell from your code but it appears maybe you are trying to call .append in a loop rather than building your data and then letting D3 add all the notes in a single statement.

It might be helpful for you to put your complete code in a JSFiddle so we can see all of what you're trying.

Comment: This is a little bit confusing to me... probably because I am new to d3 and I don't understand all of the semantics. However I have answered this question thanks to the poster above, but as a secondary question, do you have any idea why when I stroke the shapes I've made, the stroke looks weird? heres the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uZT6t/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use loop. Here is a modified code:

```
var elementTags = ["Google", 4, "Wikipedia", "Yahoo!", "Cindy"];
var _s32 = (Math.sqrt(3)/2);
var A = 75;

var svgContainer = d3.select("body") //create container
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 1000);

for (index = 0; index < elementTags.length; index++) {
    var xDiff = Math.random()*100+100;
    var yDiff = Math.random()*100+100;
    var pointData = [
        [A+xDiff, 0+yDiff]
        , [A/2+xDiff, (A*_s32)+yDiff]
        , [-A/2+xDiff, (A*_s32)+yDiff]
        , [-A+xDiff, 0+yDiff]
        , [-A/2+xDiff, -(A*_s32)+yDiff]
        , [A/2+xDiff, -(A*_s32)+yDiff]
        , [A+xDiff, 0+yDiff]
    ];

    var enterElements = svgContainer.selectAll("path.area") //draw element
        .data([pointData]).enter().append("path")
        .style("fill", "#ff0000")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.area());
}
```

Is it doing what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is. But how come when I add `.style("stroke", "1767AD")` to the code, the stroke looks weird (it has lines coming off of the hexagon and such.)

Comment: There is a bug with your approach to draw a hexagon. Try to draw it with [polygon](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_polygon.asp) tag (this fiddle can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/4xXQT/ [(с)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204562))